# I've been programing for six year and my homework in University gets marked down for coding style

Tags: coding-style

I've been programming for the last 6 years. I just recently started my first degree in computer science. My work seems to be constantly marked down for different reasons, amongst many of them:

- Uncommented code
- Writing too long identifier names and methods
- Writing too many methods

After working as a programmer for six years for numerous startup companies, and absorbing best practices which include the requirement to write "self explanatory code" I find it very difficult to go back to bad practices.

What can I do?

Comment: Do what the professor expects of you so you can pass the class.

Comment: Well, be open to their opinions and don't forget that if you want a good result, do it the way the teacher wants. My coding style is different depending on the teacher. It's like in real life when you are assigned to an existing project. You got to follow their styles.

Comment: Maybe better suitable for [programmers.se]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self documented code is not synonymous with comments.

I've argued with many senior devs around this point. Code can go a long way in communicating intent but there are some things which simply cannot (and should not) be documented through code.

For example if you have a highly optimised function/method or chunk of code which is heavily coupled to the underlying problem domain and requires very specific knowledge of the business or solution. Comments are **needed** in these scenarios.

Yes, yes, comments come with there fair share of problems but this doesn't mean they aren't helpful (or mandatory in certain cases).

I can't tell you how many times I've read a colleagues line of code and thought "what the hell?!?" only for them to explain that they needed to do that due to some quirk of some library or browser we were targeting etc.

Comments are a mechanism for a developer to justify a design decision.

As for your other problems, they are subjective. How long is too long? How many is too many?
Point them at Microsoft's guidelines if you are on the MS stack or there will be countless articles for whichever language you're using...

Hope that helps.

Comment: actually I'm using Eclipse. Do you know where I can find java's best practices?

Comment: @vondip http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html#Naming Conventions check out section 24, it explains that you should avoid abbreviations etc.

Comment: @vondip also more formal: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: Expanded upon this here: http://www.adamjamesnaylor.com/2012/11/13/Comments-Are-Not-The-Same-As-Self-Documenting-Code.aspx